# Retrofit not parsing in Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, pojo

I am having trouble parsing the values and displaying in the `recyclerview` made the `Pojo` class's in `jsonschema2pojo`, but when i run the app, it shows the toast in the enqueue `OnFailure()`, i tried multiple things but no success any help i think it can be about the expecting `jsonArray`/`jsonObject` thing ?

Thank you in advance.

I want to get the values inside the array `results[]`

Json response given below:

```
  "success": true,
  "metadata": {
    "sort": "POPULARITY",
    "total_products": 20,
    "title": "Phones & Tablets",
    "results": [
      {
        "sku": "1",
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy S9",
        "brand": "Samsung",
        "max_saving_percentage": 30,
        "price": 53996,
        "special_price": 37990,
        "image": "https://cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s9-.jpg",
        "rating_average": 5
      },
```

APIReponse pojo class:

```
public class APIReponse {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("metadata")
    @Expose
    private Metadata metadata;
```

MetaData pojo class:

```
public class MetaData {
    @SerializedName("sort")
    @Expose
    private String sort;
    @SerializedName("total_products")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalProducts;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> results = null;
```

Result pojo class:

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private String sku;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("brand")
    @Expose
    private String brand;
    @SerializedName("max_saving_percentage")
    @Expose
    private Integer maxSavingPercentage;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private Integer price;
    @SerializedName("special_price")
    @Expose
    private Integer specialPrice;
    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @SerializedName("rating_average")
    @Expose
    private Integer ratingAverage;
```

This is retrofit API interface:

```
    @GET("search/phone/page/1/")
    Call<List<Result>> getAllPhones();
```

Retrofit call methods:

```
        Call<List<Result>> call = service.getAllPhones();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Result>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Result>> call, Response<List<Result>> response) {
                generatePhonesList(response.body());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Result>> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
      });
    }

    private void generatePhonesList(List<Result> phonesList){
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        adapter = new PhonesAdapter(phonesList,this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Would be nice to se your POJO classes first.

Comment: @ArbenMaloku thank you, i made the change!

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Hello @Botz is : Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ , the json start as a object, and the data i want to parse is inside an array, so im a bit confused

Comment: @vpedro72 You can check my edited answer thanks to #Botz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use your APIResponse Class as Result from your call

```
@GET("search/phone/page/1/")
Call<APIResponse> getAllPhones();
```

and you have to change your onResponse Method:

```
      call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse> call, Response<APIResponse> response) {
                generatePhonesList(response.body().metadata.results);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<APIResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
      });
```

Comment: Hello @Botz thank you for your help, iam still having trouble, my onResponse dont work well i use your code, or i try any change i get some conflict between the Call method using the class's, any suggestion?

Comment: Oh yes, there was a little mistake in my code sample, it has to be Callback<APIResponse> and in the onFailure it has to be Call<APIResponse> 
I have changed it in the sample code.

Comment: Can you just confirme me if the OnResponse have to have the Call as ApiResponse call and the Response as ListResults, they are in conflict, iam sorry for all the trouble!

Comment: Oh sorry of course not, the Response have to be also from type APIResponse

Comment: thanks, should i change something in my generatePhonelist method or change anything in the adapter ("Iam passing the Results as a list in adapter) , because this line : "               generatePhonesList(response.body().metadata.results);
" isnt wotking i only can do response.body().getMetadata"  and it gets errors"

Answer (score 0):

You need create data class same:

```
class DataResponse {
val success: String = ""
val metadata: MetadataResponse? = null

class MetadataResponse {
    val sort: String = ""
    val total_products: Int = 0
    val title: String = ""
    val results: List<ItemResult> = arrayListOf()
    class ItemResult {
        val sku: String = ""
        val name: String = ""
        val brand: String = ""
        val max_saving_percentage: Int = 0
        val price: Int = 0
        val special_price: Int = 0
        val image: String = ""
        val rating_average: Int = 0
    }
}
```

And:

```
@GET("search/phone/page/1/")
Call<DataResponse> getAllPhones();
```

And:

```
Call<DataResponse> call = service.getAllPhones();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DataResponse> call, Response<DataResponse> response) {
            val itemResults = response.metadata?.results
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Result>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should use **APIReponse** instead of **Result** class

Like this.

```
@GET("search/phone/page/1/")
Call<APIReponse> getAllPhones();
```

Comment: and maybe without List, just Call<ApiResponse> getAllPhones();